# Is there a way to override code generator for DataSet?

Tags: c#, oracle, visual-studio-2010, code-generation

I am using a DataSet (please do not ask why) with Oracle data provider (Oracel.DataAccess.dll) and I do not like some on the generated code.

Is there a way to override code generator for DataSet? What if I use a different data provider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because you're using DataSets does not imply code generation. So what are you using/doing exactly that generates code?

A dataProvider does not imply that code is generated either. You can access your data directly and populate your datasets with data yourself.

For example

```
#region GetPostsFeatured

internal DbDataReader GetPostsFeatured()
{
  using (var command = CreateCommandForGetPostsFeatured())
  {
    DbConnection.Open();
    return command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
  }
}

internal DataSet GetPostsFeaturedDataSet()
{
  var adapter = DbProviderFactory.CreateDataAdapter();
  adapter.SelectCommand = CreateCommandForGetPostsFeatured();
  var ds = new DataSet();
  adapter.Fill(ds);
  return ds;
}

private DbCommand CreateCommandForGetPostsFeatured()
{
  var command = DbConnection.CreateCommand();
  command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
  command.CommandText = "GetPostsFeatured";
  var parameter = DbProviderFactory.CreateParameter();
  parameter.DbType = DbType.Int32;
  parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
  parameter.ParameterName = "@RETURN";
  command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
  return command;
}

#endregion GetPostsFeatured
```

The code above uses ADO.NET core (which is what I think you're using as well). Note that there are two methods

1. GetPostsFeatured() - which returns a
   DbDataReader
2. GetPostsFeaturedDataSet() - which
   returns a DataSet

Notice how the DataSet is being populated with data from the database?

In this case I'm using the MS SQL dataprovider but it could be any data provider. They all support a common set of functionality.

The code that using the config file's connectionstring section and instantiates a connection etc. is shown below

```
  internal partial class DataModule
  {
    private DbProviderFactory DbProviderFactory { get; set; }
    private DbConnection DbConnection { get; set; }

    public DataModule()
    {
      var connectionStringSettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Orion"];
      DbProviderFactory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(connectionStringSettings.ProviderName);
      DbConnection = DbProviderFactory.CreateConnection();
      DbConnection.ConnectionString = connectionStringSettings.ConnectionString;
    }
  }
```

On my blog, there is an article about a tool I've written that generates code directly from stored procedures (All the code I've shown you here is generated code). The source code of the tool is also available so you can modify the generated code and anything else you desire.
[Data Access Layer CodeGen](http://www.matlus.com/data-access-layer-codegen/)

Answer (score 0):

You can write [partial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) class and add your own function with functional you like